# Why does Kerrigan make the Zerg attack during Valerian's experiments?

Tags: starcraft

After being restored to her human form, Kerrigan is contained and experimented on by Valerian. During this period, Valerian wants to find out whether she can still command Zerg, and asks her to take control of a drone and build a hive and some other units.

At the beginning of this she asks

> “Are you really asking me to take control of a Zerg mind? Do you know what could happen?”

She makes the outcome seem unforeseeable, but we see that she has good control over them. So at this point this clearly turns out to not have been an issue (not sure if she knew beforehand that it would not be an issue). Further, however, she proceeds to make the Zerg attack their level of the facility, causing significant damage. Why?

She makes it sound like she wanted to demonstrate how unpredictable the Zerg are:

> “Funny thing about the Zerg, Valerian, they never do what you expect.”

But they are not unpredictable at all, they did exactly as she commanded and stood down when she wanted them to. The main thing this seems to demonstrate is that the Zerg are powerful, which everybody was up to speed on. It also demonstrates that she can control them (Valerian's initial question), but that was already clear by then.

Answer (score 4):

**She incredibly tired of being a puppet.**

The point that she is making to Valerian isn't that the Zerg are unpredictable, it's that she is.

Yeah, Valerian (and presumably everyone else) wants to know if she will revert back to being the Queen of Blades.  A test of Zerg control ... doesn't actually tell them anything about that, beyond that if she does, how screwed they are.  It tells them that Kerrigan can be a Zerg weapon without being Queen of Blades again.  They wouldn't want to know that, unless they were wondering about using her.

Kerrigan just got her full mind back after years of being the Zerg Overmind's puppet.  Which she ended up in after being backstabbed by Mengsk, after years of being *his* puppet.  Where she ended up after being the Confederate's puppet... you get the idea, right?

How much of her actions as the Queen of Blades were her own will and how much were the Overmind's programming is an open question - it's clear she'd rather be human, but also she remembers much more she doesn't want to go into.  Killing off all rivals and becoming unquestioned head of the Zerg could be equal parts evolutionary imperative of Blades and desperate need to secure herself from enemies by Kerrigan.

She doesn't want to revisit that.  She doesn't want to be used.  She doesn't want the experiments to continue.  She's tired, stressed, unstable, naturally, with all she's been through.  She wants her chance and attempt to be normal again, and right then, *Valerian is screwing with that.*

Thus the attack.  Roughly translated, she's saying, "You're toying with me.  I don't like it.  You are not in control, I am.  Keep it up, *you won't like it either.*"

Comment: Seems possible, but I don't see anything supporting it in the scene. Nowhere does the question come up of her powers being used to serve the Dominion, and nowhere does she rebuke that she's figured out some ostensible charade. Also, I find it puzzling that she later says “you can't control the Zerg”. Clearly the experiment demonstrates the opposite, namely that humans can acquire the ability to control Zerg.